# How to manipulate a specific drop down list with VBA?

Tags: javascript, vba

I have a web dropdown on the intranet that I can't seem to manipulate in VBA here is a similar code example

HTML code:

```
<select id="select1">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select> - 
<select id="select2" disabled="disabled">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Here is the link of the example under :https://codepen.io/Mahdiweb/pen/OJwVoRp

I tried with the following method but without success

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
.document.getElementById("select_1").Value = "2"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
.document.getElementById("select_2").Value = "1"
```

Comment: Are you sure your JS does want you want currently? You seem to be manipulating select element 1 in a non-standard fashion. There are plenty of existing questions showing you how to use VBA to alter .Selected property of a `select` element, as well as how to alter the attributes of an element and attach and dispatch an event such as `change`. There are methods for all of this and they by and large match their vanilla JS versions but work on ie.document node.

Comment: Hi  @QHarr, if you have an idea for macro Vba I'm interested

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selectedIndex++user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=setAttribute+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Dim+evt+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: You then need to use code from one of the other sets of examples to change the relevant attribute on the other list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me here is the solution :

```
Set evt = .Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
Set lst = .Document.getElementById("select1")
lst.selectedIndex = 2
lst.dispatchEvent evt
Set lst = .Document.getElementById("select2")
lst.selectedIndex = 1
lst.dispatchEvent evt
```